# issue with datagridview saving to database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am creating a sales grid in which it displays all the stock that a shop has and the user has to change the sold and sales amount cells of a datagridview.
if there is 0's in the two columns (SoldQty and SalesAmount) it will save every row in the database.
if there is nothing in the two columns (SoldQty and SalesAmount) it will throw an exception when it is trying to convert the soldqty

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        If IsNumeric(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4)) And IsNumeric(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5)) Then
```

This is for Checking to see if there is anything in the last two columns

```
 InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MovementQtyHangers", CInt(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value * -1)) '5
```

This is throwing the exception when there is nothing in the last two columns.

```
CLng(IIf(DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value = "", 0, DataGridView1.Rows(x).Cells(4).Value))
```

I could use this for the exception but I would still have the same problem of it saving every record in the data grid and the database getting very large very quickly.
any suggestions would be grateful.

Comment: Are you wanting to stop the inset process completely or just skip rows that have problems? Do you need to be able to identify those rows that have issues for the user?

Comment: If there is a 0 in both cell 4 or cell 5 then i want it to skip to the next row to check if that has a 0 and only save when there is a 1 or higher in ether cell

Comment: You would need to force a next in your loop if the check on those columns fails.  That will bypass the rest of the loop and move to the next row, if the check passes it will continue through the rest of your code in the loop.